# Erratic behavior of Javascript - Cannot read property 'longitude' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

I'm working on an Angular App, which loads data from an API.

Everything is working as expected, except periodic receiving this bug in Chrome console.log

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'longitude' of undefined

[image: updateMapWaypoint error]

This causes some of the subsequent functions to disfunction aswell. The line angular complains at, is the following

```
    function updateMapWaypoint(lastposition) {
        console.log("updateMapWaypoint(%s) called", lastposition);
        console.log($scope.units[$scope.selectedUnitIndex]);
        var longitude = (lastposition) ? $scope.units[$scope.selectedUnitIndex].lastposition.gps.longitude : $scope.unsortedPositions[$scope.selectedPositionIndex].gps.longitude;
```

Where to two first is debugging and the last one, the line causing trouble. As far as I can see from the printet object in the console. Javascript should have no trouble locating longitude from the object, however it throws the error and I can't find any way to solve it.

All help is appreciated and if more details is required, I'll provide if possible for me.

Comment: Well for whatever reason the error means that one of those `lastposition` objects does not have a "gps" property, or that it's value is `undefined`.

Comment: Better way to catch the problem break your line#314 to multiple line with if else and multiple line. You can get which line and which object is acutually being undefined.

Comment: Since `gps` shows up in the console, my guess is that you're making an AJAX request to fetch the data but the request has not yet returned before you try to use the response. The console doesn't give a snapshot in time. It gives a live view of the object.

Comment: @Pointy I kinda figured that and thats the reason why I added the console.log to see if I it was indeed undefined, however, it seems from the console.log that the object is complete?

Comment: @squint yes I'm using angular $resource to fetch the data from the API, And I'm quite sure I have control of when the appropriate data is returned before handling it using the $promise.

Comment: console.log will show you the object _as it is right now_, not what is was when you called `console.log()`. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(lastposition))`, does this give you a different result?

Comment: we have no idea what `$scope.units[$scope.selectedUnitIndex].lastposition` is

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost Using console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.units[$scope.selectedUnitIndex])); I can see that apparently there is no response on the child 'lastposition', so I guess I don't have complete control over my responses yet :)

Comment: You're logging `lastposition` but the error is from one of the other objects you access in the expression.

Comment: @charlietfl is just an object containing data received from multiple API endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might be a race condition.

`console.log()` will show you the object as it is *right now*, and *not* what is was when you called `console.log()`. To see the properties of an object at a certian point in time you must copy its content and send them to `console.log()`, for example by stringifying it:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

Or if you are using Angular:

```
console.log(angular.extend({}, myObject));
```

This is confusing (it has messed with me several times). Remember that you are sending `console.log()` an *object reference*, not a copy of the object.

Comment: As note above, seems you are completely correct and after realizing this I think I found the flaw in my logic

Comment: As a simple note, one could also use console.log(angular.extend( {}, myObject )) if traversing the object is desired